# Incorporating social media into a single app

Tags: facebook, twitter, social-networking, social-media

Just a quick question out of interest, I'm currently learning Java with Android Studio and just want to know how I would add my social media to an app or if its even possible. For example if I wanted my Facebook newsfeed or my Twitter feed to appear in my application so that I could scroll through them, this is simply out of interest and I wish to expand my knowledge of the language and how I can incorporate different facilities.

Thanks
Hadleigh

Comment: Way to broad. If you want to know how to use those social platforms from within your app, then start by reading their API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a simple **WebView** and just display the contents of the social media websites in you app, or you can use the **APIs** that are provided by the networks. The first option would be much easier do develop, but I think
the second answer is more what you're looking for.

See https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public for more infos about the Twitter API.

Or see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api for facebook.

With the APIs, you would do a GET or POST request to a specific URL and get a reply. With this reply you would display for example a users twitter timeline in you app. For more information about how this is working see the wiki.

Comment: Thank you very much Its exactly what I'm looking for, just need to read up and learn how to implement the system and get the posts.